# How can I set Undertow properties in JoinFaces/Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, undertow, joinfaces

Until now we used Wildfly 12 and increased the http max-parameters value inside the undertow module (server->http-listener) in the standalone.xml configuration file.

Now we switched to the Spring ecosystem using JoinFaces and don't know how to configure Undertow properly. According to the JoinFaces wiki the jsf.undertow namespace should be used inside the application.properties file. So we ran our app trying several solutions (like jsf.undertow.http.max-parameters=5000), but none worked so far.

Can this even be done in the property file or do we need a programmatic solution?

Comment: I submitted a ticket to Spring Boot to have Undertow properties added: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16077

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

I only see these properties available for Undertow.

```
server.undertow.accesslog.dir= # Undertow access log directory.
server.undertow.accesslog.enabled=false # Whether to enable the access log.
server.undertow.accesslog.pattern=common # Format pattern for access logs.
server.undertow.accesslog.prefix=access_log. # Log file name prefix.
server.undertow.accesslog.rotate=true # Whether to enable access log rotation.
server.undertow.accesslog.suffix=log # Log file name suffix.
server.undertow.buffer-size= # Size of each buffer.
server.undertow.direct-buffers= # Whether to allocate buffers outside the Java heap. The default is derived from the maximum amount of memory that is available to the JVM.
server.undertow.eager-filter-init=true # Whether servlet filters should be initialized on startup.
server.undertow.io-threads= # Number of I/O threads to create for the worker. The default is derived from the number of available processors.
server.undertow.max-http-post-size=-1B # Maximum size of the HTTP post content. When the value is -1, the default, the size is unlimited.
server.undertow.worker-threads= # Number of worker threads. The default is 8 times the number of I/O threads.
```

So it looks like you will have to request an issue on the Spring Boot Undertow issues to have them add it!

Request it here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues